# Combining 2 date fields for a conditional split

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, etl, conditional-split

I am new to SSIS, so please excuse me if need to clarify my problem.

We have 2 date columns, `Release Date` and `Approved Draft Release Date`.

Currently, when a date is manually entered into the Release Date column field, a SSIS package populates the Approved Draft Release Date column field with the same date. However, when the Release Date is changed and the package is rerun, the Approved Draft Release Date is also changed

We created an additional Data Flow Task in the package with the purpose of changes to the Release Date not overwriting the Approved Draft Release Date. However, the condition I have included in the Conditional Split is not working.

```
NULL([Release Date]), > ([Approved Draft Release Date])
```

I hope that someone will please take a look at the condition and let me know what we are missing.

Thank you so much in advance for any suggestions that can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NULL([Release Date]), > ([Approved Draft Release Date])
```

is not a valid expression. It looks like you need the following.

```
ISNULL([Release Date]) == False && [Release Date] > [Approved Draft Release Date]
```

Note that `NULL(typedesc)`  Returns a null value of a requested data type. To check if a column is null you can use `ISNULL()` function

Comment: Thank you so much for much for taking your time to answer my question. Pardon the misspells. That's what I get for trying to type the question on a smart phone while standing in a TSA line.

Comment: @DavidF if you found this answer helpful you should upvote it, if it solved your issue then you have to accept it. Read more in the [Tour page](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @DavidF happy to help